# Select entries in one dataframe based on cross-sectional statistic of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select the entries of one dataframe, say df2, based on the cross-sectional statistic of another dataframe, say df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5, 9, 11],
               [3, 1, 45, 1],
               [88, 314, 2, 313]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['h','e','l','p'],
               ['m','y','q','u'],
               ['e','r','y','.']], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

For instance, if the cross-sectional statistic on df1 is a max operation, then for the 3 rows in df1 the corresponding columns with the max entries are 'D', 'C', 'B' (corresponding to entries 11, 45, 314).

Selecting only those entries in df2 should give me:

[image]

which I can achieve by:

```
mask_ = pd.DataFrame(False, index=df1.idxmax(1).index, columns=df1.idxmax(1))
for k,i in enumerate(df1.idxmax(1)):
    mask_.loc[k, i] = True
df2[mask_]
```

However, this feels cumbersome; is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution working if index and columns names are same in both DataFrames.

Use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with mask for compare maximal values by all values of rows:

```
df = df2.where(df1.eq(df1.max(axis=1), axis=0))
print (df)
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  NaN  NaN    p
1  NaN  NaN    q  NaN
2  NaN    r  NaN  NaN
```